# async function : TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Tags: angular, async-await

I using Angular 9 with v10.16.0 for my project.

I have to add a function to call Aws amplify. The code is provided by aws:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signUp() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signUp({
            username,
            password,
            attributes: {
                email,          // optional
                phone_number,   // optional - E.164 number convention
                // other custom attributes 
            }
        });
        console.log({ user });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
}
```

When I add this code, I got this error : `TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`.

Should I add or import something special in the code in order to use async/await ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line is that error? Can you post the full stack with corresponding lines.

Comment: @Phix the error is on the function declaration async function signUp()

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution. My async function is in an export class. So I just remove the wording function before the name of the fucntion. For example in order to have async function signUp(), I just pust async signUp() and it's done.